# How to design a floated button like in the attached image

Tags: java, android, windows

I am trying to create an app and I have a design already as an image, but I can not clone the exact shape of the button which is above the tabs

I expect the same design in this image: below
Note:
0 and 0.00EGP should be variables

[image]

Comment: Use cardview as parent layout.

Comment: @bee Parent for which element?

Comment: This is simple layout, why are you struggle? You already have done more critical stuff shown in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a XML file **bottom_corner.xml** for background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#0091fa"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0091fa" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Now create layout **floated_button.xml** and use this background here in the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_corner"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_total_value"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_egp_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.00 EGP"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_total_value"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Charge"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_total_value"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it gives me an error: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class shape
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class shape

Comment: @mohamedShawky, You should inflate the `layout.xml` not the `shape.xml`

Comment: @JaneAlam How to make it floating at the bottom?

Comment: If you do not want to use a round corner then 
<corners android:radius="0dp"/>
use android:radius = 0dp

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, you can move forward like this:

> First of all, you have to create a `drawable file` of round background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

> Then, you can add the `tag of image` and place it, on the corner of the image where you want to place it. Then use drawable as `background` then adjust the `TextView` on it.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivLauncher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBg"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/round_text_bg"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivLauncher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivLauncher"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/ivLauncher"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ivLauncher"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivBg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/ivBg"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ivBg"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/ivBg"/>
```

Here is the result:

[Flotted Button design on image corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eEcY.png)

Comment: this is not the expected button. Please read description carefully. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain this question, your question seems like confusing as the question statement and explanation are not matched.